# Misalignment of vertical line through middle of table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

SO I am creating a table, but the alignment of the vertical line is off. The code looks like this:

```
\begin{table}
\small
\hline
\begin{tabular}{p{0.07\linewidth}||p{0.07\linewidth} p{0.07\linewidth}p{0.07\linewidth}p{0.07\linewidth} p{0.07\linewidth}|p{0.07\linewidth}p{0.07\linewidth} p{0.07\linewidth}p{0.07\linewidth}p{0.07\linewidth}p{0.07\linewidth}|} 
 & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Baseline specification}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{Robustness specification}} \\
    \hline
\textbf{Variables} & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8) & (9) & (10) \\
    \hline
    Default risk & 8.04 (2.57)^{***} & 0.22 (0.39) & 0.20 (0.36) & 3.38 (1.26)^{***} & 3.30 (1.25)^{**} & 4.48 (11.48) & 0.36 (2.09) & 4.09 (2.95)  & -45.27 (19.51)^{**} &  28.10 (13.01)^{*}
    \\
    \hline
    Liquidity & -0.16 (0.08)^{***} &  0.02 (0.03) & 0.05 (0.03) &  -0.02 (0.03) &  -0.02 (0.03) & 201.44 (107.13)^{*}  & 38.91 (23.61) & 7.96 (12.16) & 346.21 (37.71)^{***} &   2187.21 (1031.47)^{*}
    \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{.}
\label{Table 1.}
\end{table}
```

I excluded many rows but the vertical line is many times misaligned.

But the vertical line is not aligned for many rows. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with the amount of content you want to cram within the text block width. It's probably better to stack this into a larger (taller) table. Here's one option using design elements from [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\sstar}{\textsuperscript{*}}
\newcommand{\dstar}{\textsuperscript{**}}
\newcommand{\tstar}{\textsuperscript{***}}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ l *{5}{ r @{\hspace{.5\tabcolsep}} l } }
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{10}{c}{\textbf{Baseline specification}} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-11}
  \textbf{Variables} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(4)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(5)} \\
  \midrule
  Default risk &   8.04  & (2.57)\tstar & 0.22 & (0.39) & 0.20 & (0.36) &   3.38  & (1.26)\tstar &   3.30  & (1.25)\dstar \\
  Liquidity    & $-0.16$ & (0.08)\tstar & 0.02 & (0.03) & 0.05 & (0.03) & $-0.02$ & (0.03)       & $-0.02$ & (0.03)       \\
  
  \addlinespace[.5\normalbaselineskip]
  
  & \multicolumn{10}{c}{\textbf{Robustness specification}} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-11}
  & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{(6)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(7)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(8)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(9)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(10)} \\
  \midrule
  Default risk &   4.48 & (11.48)        &  0.36 & (2.09)  & 4.09 & (2.95)  & $-45.27$ & (19.51)\dstar &   28.10 & (13.01)\sstar   \\
  Liquidity    & 201.44 & (107.13)\sstar & 38.91 & (23.61) & 7.96 & (12.16) &  346.21  & (37.71)\tstar & 2187.21 & (1031.47)\sstar \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```